# Don't change the design when language of phone changed

Tags: android, right-to-left

hello i'm a new android developer and I create an android app.
when the language of phone is English everything is good but when i change it to a right to left language (for example Persian or Arabic) location of views are changed.  what should i do?  thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add the following line to the `application` node's attributes:

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Your final code should look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you probably meant -> android:supportsRtl="false"